# AsyncTasks takes several seconds to start

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my app, i have an Activity A that hosts `Fragments`.

From an (child) `Activity B`, I display a specific `Fragment` in `Activity A`, then finish B. let's call this `Fragment F1`.
In F1, I create an `AsyncTask` to read data from my database.
The `AsyncTask` is created at the end of the F1 `onCreateView` method.

The effective call stack is this one :

```
B onDestroy

F1 OnCreate

Task onPreExecute

A onResume

F1 OnResume
```

Task `doInBackground`

The `Task.doInBackground` can take up to 10 seconds before being executed.

My question is : why is the task so long to execute? According to the call stack, i think the Task waits the Thread UI to finish before starting. Or this is not the expected behavior of an `AsyncTask`.

Here's my code :

```
private class DataRetriever extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        LogUtil.LOGE("Executing AnalyseScreen.DataRetriever onPreExecute");
        // display a loader on screen while user is waiting
        progressLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        LogUtil.LOGD("Data retreiver : doInBackground start");
        reloadDatas();
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
        // hide loader then update UI
        progressLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

F1 onCreateView :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
     // doing UI stuff
     new DataRetriever().execute();
}
```

Any kind of idea?

[EDIT]
The UI stuff described in comment in onCreateView is inflating view, initialize View's variables and initialize some ClickListener in the layout.
Beside of this, F1 is accessible from A directly, without coming from B.

F1 summarize some datas, and is directly accessible. B is the end of a cycle of data. At this moment, I want the user to see directly his history. Like a running app by example

The Task doInBackground execute only after the log "AsyncTask #XX calls detach()
but i don't know what it means.

Comment: What is LogUtil for, and how does it look like? Does it have any advantage over `Log.e(TAG, "showing progressLoader");`?

Comment: LogUtil is a custom class doing a Log.e and a file log in the SD for debug purposes. See it like a simple log.

Comment: Do i understand that right: between the opening of the loading screen and "doInBackground start" in the log are up to 10 seconds? You could put log.e everywhere to see the exact code line.

Comment: it's 10s between onPreExecute and doInBackground.
While i'm doing a lot of asyncTask, i'm looking around the pool executor

Comment: The only way i can think of that would be possible is of you're somehow giving the device so much to do that it can't create another process for the background task. Will research that detach calling thing after breakfast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it !

I have a lot of `AsyncTasks`in my app and it seems that this one, when coming from `Activity B` is in queue and waits for others to finish.

There are two solutions :

- Cancel others tasks
- Execute this task in the parallel executor :

  ```
  new DataRetreiver().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (Void)null);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataReceiver` does indeed only start when your "doing UI stuff" is done, which probably is for the best if your onPostExecute() wants to access that UI stuff.

You could of course put the "UI stuff" in the `DataReceiver`s onPreExecute, minus stuff that needs to be in the onCreateView (not sure here, just dont want to destroy anything, I would guess the `inflater.inflate(stuff)` which needs to be returned).

You could also start an AsyncTask which only downloads and/or computes stuff in your `onCreate` and set some kind of callback or something in the `onPostExecute` (`someHandler.post(updateUIRunnable)` for example).